# How to solve" Import 'mplfinance' could not be resolved'"?

Tags: python

[how to solve this problem? I don't know much about programming.Please answer as clealy as possible.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PKPxs.png)

Comment: Posting an image of your code is very bad SO practice. Also, there isn't enough info. Do you have this module installed?

Answer (score 0):

1 - for import some library (use that ) you should install that before

if you don't install library and import that receive error module not found
for install library you should use pip tools that is command line base tools
install and active that in your operation system then run command

```
pip install <lib-name>
```

for install library by name  (replace this with your lib name)

2 - if have resolve error in install that check Internet connection or dns resolver and ...

3 - if install and can not import that
you have multi version of python in system and should use pip with postfix like:

```
pip3.8 for python version 3.8
3.8 or pip3.5
```